# What plot should I use? (glm predicted vs actual)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, predictive-models

I have made a linear regression model (using the glm function) to predict the number of medals a country will win based on GDP. I have the data for the actual number of medals won.

I can't seem to find the best way to plot my predicted values against the actual number of medals by country. Any suggestions on what the best kind of plot would be?

Thanks!

```
#Example data
Country <- c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Armenia")
GDP <- c(200, 400, 9)
Medal2008 <- c(1,4,3)
Medal2012 <- c(2,4,4) #actual number of medals in 2012
data <- data.frame(Country, GDP, Medal2008, Medal2012) 

Model = glm(Medal2008 ~ GDP , data=data) 
#linear regression based on 2008 medal count 

new_data = data.frame(Contry=data$Country, GDP=data$GDP, MedalCount="Predicted")
pred_2012 = predict(Model, newdata=new_data) #predicted medal count

predictions <- data.frame(data$Country, data$Medal2012, pred_2012) 
colnames(predictions) <- c("Country", "Medal2012", "Prediction")
```

Comment: What's wrong with plotting Medal2012 against pred_2012?

Comment: By default, R's `glm()` fits a linear model (assuming the outcome variable is conditionally normal). That's obviously badly wrong for medal counts, which are counts (only 0, 1, 2, etc, is possible) & presumably have lots of 0's. You need to fit your model with `glm(..., family=poisson)` or `family=quasipoisson` or fit a negative binomial model.

Comment: Presumably, the right plot here is a scatterplot of medal counts vs GDP, w/ the model overlaid. Can you post a small example dataset for people to work with?